# UITextView Puzzle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In one project XCode4 intellisence feature shows **setContentToHTMLString** method of **UITextView** but in other project intellisence feature not showing **setContentToHTMLString** this method of **UITextView**.

I want to use **setContentToHTMLString** method of **UITextView** for HTML-based Presentation-only in my textView this works in one Project but not showing even by the intellisence feature of **UITextView**.

Any Suggestion.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: check weather the project which has  setContentToHtmlString of textview  method is customized textview or default textview provided in the xcode.

Comment: I'm new to iphone how can we find that either this is customize textView or not because I m unable to find any thing new in this accept this @interface UITextView (extended)
- (void)setContentToHTMLString:(NSString *) contentText;

this program used this interface in .m file
@end

Comment: The answer given below is right.You can use the code from the link provided by sergio i.e. it is in private API . Hope it helps you......

Comment: Ya Aman it works for me but using this apple reject my app. because of using Private Api. Can you give me suggestion if bcoz i'm received html tags after parsing the url if we display on the webView to it works normally. How can i display data on webView after parsing for displaying on the textView i used self.textView.text = [self.textView.text 
            stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n\n",capturedCharacters];

can u tell he how can i display on webView thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why Xcode has this changing behavior, but I would suggest you not to use that method, because [it is in a private API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998030/is-there-anyway-to-display-html-content-in-textview), so your app would be rejected by Apple. Possibly the fact that it is private is also why sometimes it is showing (it should not), others it is not.

The way to go to display HTML content is either use a `[UIWebView][2]`, with all its caveats, or try out [Three20](http://three20.info) styled text facilities, which are quite limited, though.

Comment: if we put parsed data directly to UIWebView then html tags are works normally or not.

Comment: UIWebView will render your HTML almost exactly like Safari would do, including CSS, Javascript and everything. Use the `-loadHTMLString:baseURL:` method.